# ¿Cómo puedo crear un usuario desde la API de Github?

Tags: api, github, rest

He buscado en la documentación de Github para consumir su API pero de momento solo puedo obtener información de cualquier usuario y sus repositorios, me gustaría realizar un POST para crear un usuario con la información que se requiera. De antemano gracias. Saludos.

Comment: Pues si en la [documentación](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/users/users) de la API no está, entonces no está disponible esa opción

Comment: Gracias  @Alfabravo no había buscado correctamente, a veces una salida para despejarse soluciona las cosas. Saludos compañero.

Answer (score 2):

Mea culpa, si existe el apartado para crear el usuario, pero estaba algo oculto y me costó encontrarlo, ya llevaba cinco horas en esto, se encuentra en esta [url](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.22/rest/reference/enterprise-admin#create-a-user). Mil disculpas porque no busqué de forma correcta, y de antemano gracias. Saludos

Comment: Buen hallazgo! Márcala como aceptada en un rato (o mañana)